# How to execute git commands in bash script by giving variables from java?

Tags: java, git, bash, shell

I want to run the "git checkout " command using Java. I am using bash script to do so and I am unable to pass arguments to the script? Can someone suggest a solution?

Code that I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
String path="path/to/repo";
String branch="newBranch";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/revert.bat",path,branch);
Process p = pb.start();    
p.waitFor();              
System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
}
```

Bash script is:

```
cd $1
git checkout $2
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: which argument is need to pass?

Comment: path and the branch that are specified in String variables

Comment: Hey just a suggestion: have you thought about using JGit? It'll make implementing this a lot cleaner and it'll all be in your code as opposed to a bash script.  https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit

Comment: Jgit lacks a feature to 'revert a merge' which is where I am stuck. Hence I am using bash script for that function

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code seems fine. I did a test on my site, pass "hello" and "world " to test.bat, and print them to a file test.txt, it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/test.bat","hello","world");
    Process p;
    try {
        p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    System.out.println("Script executed successfully");

}
```

Code of test.bat is below:

```
@echo off
echo %0 > C:\test.txt
echo %1 >> C:\test.txt
echo %2 >> C:\test.txt
@echo on
```

And the test.txt will be like low:

```
test.bat 
hello 
world
```

So I suggest that you can print the arguments in your bat file and check what the bat file received, and also check whether it is ok to run the bat file with those arguments in CMD directly.
FYI.